# Ubuntu Wayland is using Xorg session?

Tags: xorg, 17.10, desktop-environments

I noticed in my logs that Xorg session was active despite not using the Xorg login.

When checking with `ls -lah /usr/share/xsessions/` I got the following output:

```
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Nov  4 21:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 302 root root  12K Nov 16 02:40 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   19 Oct 13 12:33 ubuntu.desktop -> ubuntu-xorg.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  262 Oct 13 12:33 ubuntu-xorg.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  249 Oct 13 12:33 unity.desktop
```

It seems that the `Ubuntu.desktop` session is also using `xorg.desktop`.
Is there an issue with this? Has someone hacked my account running xorg compatible programs in a session that should not be xorg.

Thank you in advanced for any information on why xorg is showing up in a non-xorg session!

Comment: At the login screen, when you clicked on the little gear, was "Wayland" offered as a selection?  Did you select it?  Everything else is xorg.

Comment: There is an xorg option, but I selected "ubuntu desktop" which I thought was a Wayland session.

If you look at my readout you can see there are 3 options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. Do this simple check and see if you are really using Wayland (and not X11).

Open a Terminal window on the Ubuntu Desktop and run these commands:

```
# VERIFY that you are indeed using the Wayland Display Manager,
# and NOT X11 which would return "x11".
echo ${XDG_SESSION_TYPE}
if [ "${XDG_SESSION_TYPE}" != "wayland" ]; then
    echo "ERROR. This session does not use the Wayland Display Manager."
    echo "       Your system uses ${XDG_SESSION_TYPE}"
else 
    echo "OK. This session uses the Wayland Display Manager."
fi
```

b. Check the process list to see if Xorg is really active)

```
$ ps -fe | grep Xorg
```

> Output on Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful) Wayland:
>     ubuntu 1907 1498  0 09:52 pts/0  00:00:00 grep --color=auto xorg
>
> Output on Ubuntu 17.04 X11:
>     root   1110   960  0 Nov20 tty7  00:06:58 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
>     root  26750 26399  0 09:56 pts/4 00:00:00 grep --color=auto Xorg

c. If you cat the ubuntu.desktop then you will see that it starts the main Gnome session. If this config file somewhere contains "unity" then you are not using the Wayland display manager.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu on Xorg
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu  gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=gnome-shell
Icon=
Type=Application
DesktopNames=ubuntu:GNOME
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

d. The filename "ubuntu-xorg.desktop" is probably a leftover from the previous version of Ubuntu. It gives the impression to be Xorg related but the contents are definitely not.

Comment: Thank you @Rolf `echo ${XDG_SESSION_TYPE}` came back as "Wayland" and checking the other points also came back as your expected outputs. Thanks for being so thorough!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your graphics drivers, Wayland may not work on your system, and Xorg is automatically used instead, though Wayland is the default now.

Also, under a Wayland session there is Xwayland, so that apps which do not work as Wayland clients but do work under Xorg, can still be run. Some apps (such as screen recording/streaming apps) will still not work though, due to the enhanced security of Wayland.